# make: more than one % in dependency

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would love to use template dependency of the following form

```
data/%/ld.data :: data/%/%LD.jsn
```

Now, only the first percent sign in dependency `data/%/%LD.jsn` is replaced by the directory from the target, as specified in the GNUmake manual

Is there any simple way to get the desired functionality, that is to specify that all files of the form **data/*Folder*/ld.data** depend on the corresponding file **data/*Folder*/*Folder*LD.data**.

I can build rules with loop but this requires specifying all the relevant folders in advance and editing makefile when new folder is added (or finding them dynamically at makefile start)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a much simpler way; use automatic variables during second expansion (this is really what second expansion was originally created to allow):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
data/%/ld.data : data/$$*/$$*LD.jsn
        actions
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I have adapted from http://bitofahack.com/post/1406231094 goes like this

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
data/%/ld.data: LANGNAME=$(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $@)))
data/%/ld.data: LDFILE=data/$(LANGNAME)/$(LANGNAME)LD.jsn

data/%/ld.data: $$(LDFILE)
   actions
```

But this looks cumbersome, to say nothing about the crazy way `$(notdir ...)` and `$(dir ...)` cannot work together